# How to robocopy to copy only files without creating parent folder tree of the file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I am using robocopy to copy certain files from a long hierarchy-ed folder structure. E.g.: `*.properties` files. They may reside in very deep level of the directory structure (e.g. `C:\a\v\b\g\f\aa.properties`). Now I want to copy these properties files to another keeping only the top most parent folder (e.g.: destination folder structure will be `a\aa.properties`); I have used `/S` option to do so but it includes the parents too.
Below is the batch file I've tried:

```
@echo off 

::Author = SHUBHENDU

echo Copying files from %1 to %2


set source=%1
set destination=%2

set list=abc def
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
   echo Copying files from  %%a
   ROBOCOPY %source%\%%a %destination%\%%a *_en.properties /S
))
```

Source directory (sample):

```
F:.
│   temp.bat
│
└───ss
    ├───asd
    │       ss_en.properties
    │
    └───asdfsdsd
        │   aa_en.properties
        │
        ├───dd
        │       asdsa.txt
        │
        └───ff
                ff_en.properties
```

Required destination directory:

```
F:.
├───asd
│       ss_en.properties
│
└───asdfsdsd
        aa_en.properties
        ff_en.properties
```

Comment: so you want to copy `C:\*\*\*` properties to `C:\*` properties for instance?

Comment: Yes... I've updated the structure. Pls check.

Comment: What if directory `ss` contains a file `*_en.properties` also?

Comment: @aschipfl We need to start from somewhere i.e. the root directory. In this case I set source as ss folder as it has no `*_en.properties` files; if it does I would have set it's parent folder. And in that case I would have set `ss` on `list` like : `set list=ss`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the source is not the same as the destination.

NOTE!!! I have not recreated your scenario, so this is untested, just amended your code. I will fix the code based on your errors.

```
@echo off

set source=%1
set destination=%2

for %%F in (%destination%) do set destination="%%~fF"

for /r %source% %%F in (.) do if "%%~fF" neq %destination% ROBOCOPY %source%\%%F %destination%\%%F *_en.properties /S
```